# SOAP WSDL request works for one method, but not for the other - Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to currently pull some xml from a SOAP server to use in my app. I have successfully pulled one object from the server, but cannot pull another object. The first object I pull is a user's ID number. Here is the code I am using to pull the first ID number:

```
    public class logInTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "checkUserLogin";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://m";
    private static final String URL = "-sensitive information here, just know that this ends with .cfc?wsdl-";

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("usr", strings[0]);
        request.addProperty("pwd", strings[1]);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            // SoapPrimitive resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

            RESULT = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();

            return RESULT;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Error" + e);
            return "NULL";

        }

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        if(RESULT.contains("Password Incorrect")) {
            alertDialog("Your password is incorrect. Please try again.");
        } else if(RESULT.contains("User Not Found")) {
            alertDialog("You have entered a non-existing username/email. Please try again.");
        } else {
            Log.i("BEGINNINGRESULT", RESULT);
            RESULT = RESULT.substring(64);
            RESULT = RESULT.substring(0, RESULT.indexOf(";"));
            alertDialog(RESULT);
            startNewIntent(RESULT);
        }
    }

}
```

With this code, I receive a response from the server in the form of a string:

```
checkUserLoginResponse{checkUserLoginReturn=User Authenticated: 3; }
```

Now, I go over to another class for a Main Menu esque activity. Here, I am going to use the integer from the above string (3) and feed that into another SOAP request. Here is the code for that:

```
    public class getUserRegistrations extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getUserRegistrations";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://m";
    private static final String URL = "-same url-";

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... userNumber) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo user = new PropertyInfo();

        user.setName("usr");
        user.setValue(userNumber);
        user.setType(String.class);

        request.addProperty(user);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            androidHttpTransport.responseDump = requestDump;

            MainMenuActivity.registrationsGrabbed = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();

            return MainMenuActivity.registrationsGrabbed;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Error" + e);
            return "NULL";

        }

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("userID", userID);
        Log.i("dump", requestDump);
        //Log.i("Registration XML:", registrationsGrabbed);
    }

}
```

When I run the app and log in, I successfully pass the userID (userNumber in the second class) and try to pass this to the server. But, I encounter an error. In the logcat output, I see:

```
09-04 15:23:25.313  28519-28519/co.cdat.emi E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: co.cdat.emi, PID: 28519
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

and this crashes the app. The error comes from the lines:

```
 Log.i("dump", requestDump);
 //Log.i("Registration XML:", registrationsGrabbed);
```

I'm assuming these errors tell me that there is no response from the server, even though I am sending the same type of request. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? If you need more information, please ask. Thank you.